# Masonry + Bootstrap 3 vertical alignment issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to make some image gallery with bootrstrap 3.2 + Masonry 3.1.5 and my layout is wasting a lot of space, i'm not that fluent in english so i uploaded a couple images as examples.

[current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddgpm.png)

[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjMVh.png)

Here's the relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"> <!-- gallery -->
    <div class="masonry"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadImages();
    var $container = $('.masonry');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post-box',
            columnWidth: '.post-box',
            transitionDuration: 0
        });
    });
});

function loadImages() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/getImages',
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<div class="post-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"'
                          + ' src="'+data[i].src+'"></div>';
                };
                $('.masonry').html(html);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, e) {
                console.log(status, e);
            }
        });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.masonry {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
    padding: 10px;
}
.post-box {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
}
```

I could make square thumbnails of the images and make a grid of 200x200 images, but if there's a solution using different heights i'd rather use that.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like Masonry isn't even firing are there any errors on your console in your web browser? You're using jQuery by the looks of it have you made sure Masonry plugin is loaded after jQuery has loaded?

Comment: There weren't any errors and jQuery was the first script loaded. I gave up on loading the images through an ajax call and the problem was solved. Now that i think about it, the problem could be that the Masonry call was executed before the ajax response arrived and there weren't any images on that div at that momment.

Comment: You could also look at another plugin by Desandro (the guy who did masonry) http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ imagesLoaded - not sure it will help but it might.